# Request Missing a User Agent Header

Tags: http-headers, mod-security

I activated `ModSecurity` on a cheap web hosting but I have no control over it: that is, the only thing the service provider lets you do is reading logs but, unfortunately, you can't really configure `ModSecurity` yourself.

This morning I found this log:

```
[Sun Sep 16 16:50:31 2018] 
[error] 
[client 214.250.181.113] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. 
[file "/usr/local/apache2/conf/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] 
[line "65"] 
[id "960009"] 
[rev "2.1.1"] 
[msg "Request Missing a User Agent Header"] 
[severity "NOTICE"] 
[tag "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_UA"] 
[tag "WASCTC/WASC-21"] 
[tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] 
[tag "PCI/6.5.10"] 
[hostname "www.example.com"] 
[uri "/firepro/newfile.txt"]
```

I verified this happens when my `PHP` code simply tries to read and echo the contents of *newfile.txt* using `file_get_contents`. This error breaks a Wordpress widget and renders it useless (it doesn't display any content, since the content is provided by the txt file overwritten every hour by PHP with the help of a cronjob).

What header is `ModSecurity` expecting? Why do I need to specify a User Agent header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I verified this happens when my PHP code simply tries to read and echo the contents of `newfile.txt` using `file_get_contents`.

It sounds like you are requesting `newfile.txt` over HTTP instead of making a direct request on the filesystem. If you use the HTTP protocol then PHP makes an entirely separate HTTP request, using the `user_agent` value in `php.ini` - which is NULL by default. (You can set this in your script with a call like `ini_set('user_agent','my-user-agent')`).

However, if this file is on your local filesystem then you should be making a local filesystem call instead, using an *absolute filesystem path*. For example:

```
file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/newfile.txt');
```

> What header is ModSecurity expecting?

Any request from a *real* end-user *should* have a non-empty `User-Agent` header, hence the rule set by ModSecurity. (However, [the `User-Agent` header isn't strictly necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274789/is-lack-of-user-agent-in-http-request-valid) for a valid HTTP request.)